# CodeIgniter table generate with links

Tags: php, codeigniter

I will be moving the SQL code to a model once I get it working, I know it should be there. but it's not going to help anything if it's not working to start with. I may be missing something, but how do i put SQL result 'id' as the hyperlink (ex hyperlink www.mainsite.com/hw/id/$id)

I already have my index.php forwarded.

Current Controller:

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->library('table');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper(array('html','url'));

    $config['base_url'] = '/index.php/hw/id';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('HWC')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 20;
    $config['num_links'] = 1;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination pagination-centered"><ul>';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->order_by('Col');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $where = array('ModelName IS NOT NULL' => null);

    $data['records'] = $this->db->get_where('HWC', $where, $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));

    $result = $this->table->set_heading('HWC #', 'Col #', 'Model Name', 'Series', 'Color', 'Tampo', 'Base Color', 'Base Type', 'Window Color', 'Interior Color', 'Wheel Type', 'Toy #', 'Country', 'Notes', 'Series #', 'Year Produced');
    $data['main_content'] = 'hw_view';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}
```

Current View:

```
<?php
  echo $this->table->set_template(array('table_open' => '<table class="table table-condensed table-hover">'));
  echo validation_errors('<p class="error">');
  echo $this->table->generate($records);
  echo $this->pagination->create_links();
?>
```

Comment: I guess it depends on what's in the table library (Is that CI or third-party? - doesn't seem to be in the online docs), but either you should be able to define callbacks for formatting columns that would allow you to wrap an anchor around the id, or, if there's nothing in the table library, and you still want to use that library for some reason, you could modify your select statement to return the is column with added text to make it an anchor. That would be a last resort, however.

Comment: I may be using an old version of CI, I started this project about a year ago and just got back into adding onto it. I also have Bootstrap if it's easier to pull data and format it in tables with pagination with bootstrap.